# iOS 11, Xcode 9 Error: NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100

Tags: ionic2, nsurlconnection, ios11, xcode9

I'm getting this error when working in JS and Ionic 3. I'm testing on my iPhone 7 plus with iOS 11 and Xcode 9.

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
```

Anyone got a similar error in the past?

Comment: Have you fixed this? I am also facing the same issue in iOS 11

Comment: Did someone find a fix?